# How to get array of strings from DllImport

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport, kiosk

Im trying to get the array of strings from the dll.

**This is the documentation for this dll function.**

```
Request_the_Value_of_ICT_multi_Currency_Bill_Validator()
(a)Input
1. strCurrecy: AnsiString
(b)Return:pData: AnsiString*
pData[0] Value1
pData[1] Value2
...
pData[19] Value3
(c)Example:
AnsiString *pData = 
Request_the_Value_of_ICT_multi_Currency_Bill_Validator("AUD");
```

I've tried this code below and the return is some non-english language

```
IntPtr pData = Request_the_Value_of_ICT_multi_Currency_Bill_Validator("AUD");
string stringB = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pData);

string stringA = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pData);
```

**This is the dll**

```
[DllImport("PS3_DLL.dll", EntryPoint = "Request_the_Value_of_ICT_multi_Currency_Bill_Validator", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern IntPtr Request_the_Value_of_ICT_multi_Currency_Bill_Validator(string strCurrency);
```

**This is the function i got from disassembling the dll. I really got no idea what it means**

[image: This is the function i got from dis]

**UPDATE: FINALLY I GOT THE RIGHT CODE!**

```
 IntPtr pData = ictdll.Request_the_Country_code_of_ICT_multi_Currency_BA();

        IntPtr[] pGetData = new IntPtr[9];
        Marshal.Copy(pData, pGetData, 0, pGetData.Length);

        string[] currency = new string[9];

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            currency[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pGetData[i]);
        }
```

Comment: We don't know what the DLL's interface is.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that's also one of my problems because i dont have the dll interface.

Comment: We can't see it, it's not in the question, so nobody can answer the question as it stands. Perhaps there is something in that link, but who wants to follow off site links? If you have extra information include it here, not in an off site link.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have updated my question. I copied the content of the document and Included it in my question above.

Comment: That doesn't really specify the interface in sufficient detail

Comment: i have found a way to disassemble the dll and i found out that the code is actually written in Assembly

Comment: That doesn't sound terribly plausible

Comment: I've updated the question above I really got no idea what that code means.

Comment: I don't think you've demonstrated that the dll was written in assembly. How have you ended up trying to call a dll that has no usable documentation? This doesn't look like a path to success.

Comment: That's the current project that's given to me. The first documentation that I have provided that's the kind of reference that i've been using the entire time. I've made the other dll's that returns integer work (although it takes too much time until I make it work)  until I encounter that one that returns a string. I've tried everything but it just doesn't work that's why I ended up posting my question here for the first time.

Comment: There's nothing that we can do here to help you. Without details we can't answer this question. Ask your supervisor for help.

Comment: Yeah, maybe ill try a few more things. Anyway thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After browsing for many days i finally got the right code!.

```
    IntPtr pData = ictdll.Request_the_Country_code_of_ICT_multi_Currency_BA();

    IntPtr[] pGetData = new IntPtr[9];
    Marshal.Copy(pData, pGetData, 0, pGetData.Length);

    string[] currency = new string[9];

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        currency[i] = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pGetData[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you provided clearly says `Ansi`. Also, this looks to be an *array* of string pointers, so you need to marshal the whole array.

It's unclear who is supposed to free all this memory, you may want to investigate that.

```cs
[DllImport("PS3_DLL.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi,
    CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern IntPtr[] Request_the_Value_of_ICT_multi_Currency_Bill_Validator
    (string strCurrency);
```

```cs
var arrPtr = Request_the_Value_of_ICT_multi_Currency_Bill_Validator
    (yourCurrency);

arrayOfStrings = arrPtr.Select(ptr =>
    Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(ptr)).ToArray()
```

I suggest you check the calling convention is correct. Windows API uses `StdCall`, but most C libraries use `CDecl`

Comment: Really? How will `string[]` be marshalled and the memory handled, as a return value? Who allocates what, and where is it deallocated. But this surely can't be right because even if the p/invoke marshaler is prepared to run with this, it's going to assume any memory was allocated on the COM heap, which seems a stretch. Basically the question can't be answered as it stands. Not enough info.

Comment: @Charlieface , Thanks for the answer, I've tried that one but theres an error in UnmanagedType.ByValArray. It says  ByValArray is only valid for fields.

Comment: @JomanRey OK have modified it. Still not clear who is supposed to free the memory though

Comment: That's not going to work either. This really isn't a topic for guesswork and speculation.

Comment: @Charlieface ill update my question ill provide the dll function but its written in Assembly dont know if will be of help.